# How can i know angular 7.1.4 is properly installed?

Tags: node.js, angular, installation

I installed angular 7.1.4 on my gcp ubuntu server and this is what I am getting after using the command

```
ng version


Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 8.16.2
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.1.4
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/core              7.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.4
@ngtools/webpack                  7.1.4
@schematics/angular               7.1.4
@schematics/update                0.11.4
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.23.1
```

also

```
node -v
v8.16.2
```

I also created a project using the command

```
ng new angular-demo

root@la-test-angular-node:/angular-demo# ng serve


** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2019-12-02T13:06:43.122Z
Hash: bb8b52ddfa46c6b4d208
Time: 20085ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 11.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 237 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.67 MB [initial] [rendered]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

but it's not getting open in a web browser I am getting This site can’t be reached error, I also tried

```
ng serve --host:ip-address
```

but still getting the same error, please help me out what am I doing wrong?
I don't know its angular problem or node but I am not getting the default angular page.

Thanks.

**UPDATE** I use this command as suggested and I didn't add any of my code I am just trying to open the default angular page.

```
ng serve -o --host=10.37.0.5
```

and getting this

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on 10.37.0.5:4200, open your browser on http://10.37.0.5:4200/ **

Date: 2019-12-02T13:29:53.559Z
Hash: bb8b52ddfa46c6b4d208
Time: 45913ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 11.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 237 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.67 MB [initial] [rendered]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
(node:1956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Exited with code 3
    at ChildProcess.cp.once.code (/angular-demo/node_modules/opn/index.js:84:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:336:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:561:12)
(node:1956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1956) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **ng serve -o**

(-o its used to force opening the web browser, will open at default 4200 port though)

Comment: I used this but still no luck, I update the question now I am getting something new after using `ng serve -o` command please check that out.

Comment: Seems like you've got an error because of your project's code. Check that warning '[DEP0018] DeprecationWarning'. Try to do a ng build, maybe building your project can track exactly the line of your code where that promise rejection happens. Or just share your code aswell.

Comment: I did ng build and can you tell me which file should I share because I don't know about angular I just created a project using `ng new angular-demo` and there are several files inside `angular-demo`, should I share   `main.ts` which is inside src?.

Comment: I'd say share the code you made (not the self-constructed from ng new)

Comment: I didn't make any code, I am just trying to open the default angular page in order to check whether it's working properly or not.

Comment: I see. Did you tried to remove your node_modules folder and install dependencies again ? (npm install / npm update)

Comment: I did npm update it also gets updated but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the port 4200 may be in use. You can try another port by:

```
ng serve --port 6787
```

Comment: Tried but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I tried different thing and yes the right way is using this command

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

0.0.0.0 open the host for others it means we can use port 4200 on any server, but before it didn't work because of the firewall of gcp when I open the port for 4200 then it starts working.